# How to correctly perform cross validation in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to do a cross validation on a k-nn classifier and I am confused about which of the following two methods below conducts cross validation correctly.

```
training_scores = defaultdict(list)
validation_f1_scores = defaultdict(list)
validation_precision_scores = defaultdict(list)
validation_recall_scores = defaultdict(list)
validation_scores = defaultdict(list)

def model_1(seed, X, Y):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    scoring = ['accuracy', 'f1_macro', 'precision_macro', 'recall_macro']
    model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=13)

    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
    scores = model_selection.cross_validate(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring, return_train_score=True)
    print(scores['train_accuracy'])
    training_scores['KNeighbour'].append(scores['train_accuracy'])
    print(scores['test_f1_macro'])
    validation_f1_scores['KNeighbour'].append(scores['test_f1_macro'])
    print(scores['test_precision_macro'])
    validation_precision_scores['KNeighbour'].append(scores['test_precision_macro'])
    print(scores['test_recall_macro'])
    validation_recall_scores['KNeighbour'].append(scores['test_recall_macro'])
    print(scores['test_accuracy'])
    validation_scores['KNeighbour'].append(scores['test_accuracy'])

    print(np.mean(training_scores['KNeighbour']))
    print(np.std(training_scores['KNeighbour']))
    #rest of print statments
```

It seems that for loop in the second model is redundant.

```
def model_2(seed, X, Y):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    scoring = ['accuracy', 'f1_macro', 'precision_macro', 'recall_macro']
    model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=13)

    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
    for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
        scores = model_selection.cross_validate(model, X[train], Y[train], cv=kfold, scoring=scoring, return_train_score=True)
        print(scores['train_accuracy'])
        training_scores['KNeighbour'].append(scores['train_accuracy'])
        print(scores['test_f1_macro'])
        validation_f1_scores['KNeighbour'].append(scores['test_f1_macro'])
        print(scores['test_precision_macro'])
        validation_precision_scores['KNeighbour'].append(scores['test_precision_macro'])
        print(scores['test_recall_macro'])
        validation_recall_scores['KNeighbour'].append(scores['test_recall_macro'])
        print(scores['test_accuracy'])
        validation_scores['KNeighbour'].append(scores['test_accuracy'])

    print(np.mean(training_scores['KNeighbour']))
    print(np.std(training_scores['KNeighbour']))
    # rest of print statments
```

I am using `StratifiedKFold` and I am not sure if I need for loop as in model_2 function or does `cross_validate` function already use the split as we are passing `cv=kfold` as an argument.

I am not calling `fit` method, is this OK? Does `cross_validate` calls that automatically or do I need to call `fit` before calling `cross_validate`?

Finally, how can I create confusion matrix? Do I need to create it for each fold, if yes, how can the final/average confusion matrix be calculated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) is arguably your best friend in such questions; from the simple example there it should be apparent that you should use neither a `for` loop nor a call to `fit`. Adapting the example to use `KFold` as you do:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_validate
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
n_splits = 5
kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True)

model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
scoring=('r2', 'neg_mean_squared_error')

cv_results = cross_validate(model, X, y, cv=kf, scoring=scoring, return_train_score=False)
cv_results
```

Result:

```
{'fit_time': array([0.00901461, 0.00563478, 0.00539804, 0.00529385, 0.00638533]),
 'score_time': array([0.00132656, 0.00214362, 0.00134897, 0.00134444, 0.00176597]),
 'test_neg_mean_squared_error': array([-11.15872549, -30.1549505 , -25.51841584, -16.39346535,
        -15.63425743]),
 'test_r2': array([0.7765484 , 0.68106786, 0.73327311, 0.83008371, 0.79572363])}
```

> how can I create confusion matrix? Do I need to create it for each fold

No one can tell you if you *need* to create a confusion matrix for each fold - it is your choice. If you choose to do so, it may be better to skip `cross_validate` and do the procedure "manually" - see my answer in [How to display confusion matrix and report (recall, precision, fmeasure) for each cross validation fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53531167/how-to-display-confusion-matrix-and-report-recall-precision-fmeasure-for-eac/55050146#55050146).

> if yes, how can the final/average confusion matrix be calculated?

There is no "final/average" confusion matrix; if you want to calculate anything further than the `k` ones (one for each k-fold) as described in the linked answer, you need to have available a separate validation set...

Comment: If I want to display confusion matrix for each fold, how would you do that as in my case I am using cross_validate so I don't have access to `confusion_matrix(y[val_index], pred))` as shown in your link. Because cross_validate is creating fold.

Comment: @learner you mean you are *bounded* in using `cross_validate`? Because the linked answer is the most straightforward way to do so, and you don't "lose" anything (scores etc) compared to your current approach - it is actually a (correct) modification of your `model_2` approach; in any case, you could check [`cross_val_predict`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html)

Answer (score 4):

`model_1` is correct.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html

`cross_validate(estimator, X, y=None, groups=None, scoring=None, cv=’warn’, n_jobs=None, verbose=0, fit_params=None, pre_dispatch=‘2*n_jobs’, return_train_score=’warn’, return_estimator=False, error_score=’raise-deprecating’)`

where

`estimator` is an object implementing ‘fit’. It will be called to fit the model on the train folds.

`cv`: is a cross-validation generator that is used to generated train and test splits.

If you follow the example in the sklearn docs

`cv_results = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=3, return_train_score=False)
cv_results['test_score']
array([0.33150734, 0.08022311, 0.03531764])`

You can see that the model `lasso` is fitted 3 times once for each fold on train splits and also validated 3 times on test splits. You can see that the test score on validation data are reported.

## Cross validation of Keras models

Keras provides wrapper which makes the keras models compatible with sklearn cross_validatation method. You have to wrap the keras model using `KerasClassifier`

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_validate
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

def get_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, activation='relu')) 
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model, epochs=10, batch_size=8, verbose=0)
kf = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)

X = np.random.rand(10,2)
y = np.random.rand(10,1)

cv_results = cross_validate(model, X, y, cv=kf, return_train_score=False)

print (cv_results)
```