# Simple CV for classic classification models

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm looking for the easiest way to teach my students how to perform 10CV, for standard classifiers in sklearn such as logisticregression, knnm, decision tree, adaboost, svm, etc.

I was hoping there was a method that created the folds for them instead of having to loop like below:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

X=df1.drop(['Unnamed: 0','ID','target'],axis=1).values
y=df1.target.values


for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X,y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    clf = LogisticRegressionCV()
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    train_predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_test, train_predictions)
    print(acc)
```

Seems like there should be an easier way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly perform cross validation in scikit-learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270431/how-to-correctly-perform-cross-validation-in-scikit-learn)

Comment: the thing you are looking for its called: cross validation and there are several questions regarding that topic around here

Comment: I know it's cross validation. I'm looking for the most concise function in python that implements it.

Comment: @PV8 not a bad solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is, whether there is an already existing method for 10-fold cross validation. So to answer it, there is the sklearn documentation, which explains cross validation and also how to use it:

- [Cross-validation: evaluating estimator performance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)

Besides that, you can also make use of the sklearn modules for cross validation

- [Various splitting techniques with modules](http://www.studyai.cn/modules/classes.html#splitter-classes)
- [Model validation with cross validation](http://www.studyai.cn/modules/classes.html#model-validation)

To include a code example, which should work with your code, import the required library

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
```

and add this line instead of your loop:

```
print(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10))
```

And your `n_splits` is just set to 1 by the way, so its 1-fold and not 10-fold in your code.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. How would I include normalization though, e.g. MinMaxScaler()? (This would have to be done on train and test folds separately)