# How to display mean classification report and confusion matrix in case of KFold cross validation

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I am trying to perform 5 fold cross validation in python using Keras ANN Classifier and I need a single mean classification report and confusion matrix for all the folds.

I could calculate the confusion matrix and the classification report for each fold and display them following the code snippet provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53531167/how-to-display-confusion-matrix-and-report-recall-precision-fmeasure-for-eac).

**Question:**

How can I calculate the average confusion matrix and average report for all folds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as **confusion matrix** is concerned, it's used to *sum up* the confusion matrices for each fold since they contain absolute values and not percentages. However, if you want to have an averaged confusion matrix you should create a `confusion_mat_avg` variable of the same shape and just take the mean of each cell for all folds.

About the **average report**, the solution is similar. The following answer will probably give you a better idea.

[How to compute precision,recall and f1 score of an imbalanced dataset for K fold cross validation with 10 folds in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46598301/how-to-compute-precision-recall-and-f1-score-of-an-imbalanced-dataset-for-k-fold).